Uninstall opsys package 5.15.0-112 generic?
enter image description hereI installed Linux 5.15.0-112 generic opsys update a few days ago and it resulted in stuck in black screen mode during start up. (Acer laptop, Aspire 515-43 model, GNOME desktop, Ubuntu 22.04)
Only way around was to select previous install from boot options screen Linux 5.15.0-107-generic. Must do this every time to avoid black screen lock.
Maybe there is a coding error in 5.15.0-112 update or maybe it loaded improperly.
Any suggestions on how to uninstall or recommended alternative fix? (I have accepted several software updates since the black screen issue surfaced but none seems to be a correction for possibly bad code.)

Why uninstall? if you need grub to always start with the other kernel https://askubuntu.com/questions/82140/how-can-i-boot-with-an-older-kernel-version

Thanks! This is excellent information. Much appreciated.
